# How does odr-use apply to a variable identified by a qualified-id?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

Sample code:

```
struct S
{
    static const int a = 0;
};
int const *b = &S::a;
```

My understanding of the intent of the ODR is that `S::a` should be *odr-used* here, because its address is taken.

My question is: Where and how does the Standard specify that `S::a` is *odr-used* in this code?

---

*My research so far:* The only relevant part of the C++14 standard seems to be [basic.def.odr]/3:

> A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `ex` is odr-used by `ex` unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` yields a constant expression that does not invoke any non-trivial functions and, if `x` is an object, `ex` is an element of the set of potential results of an expression `e`, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to `e`, or `e` is a discarded-value expression.

However I don't see how `S::a` fits into this. The definition of *name* ([basic]/4) excludes qualified-ids, so `x` can't refer to `S::a`  here.  I don't see any other text in the standard supporting the use of *name* to mean anything other than the definition from [basic]/4.

Maybe `x` means `a`; however `a` never appears as an expression, let alone a potentially-evaluated one: the `a` in `S::a` is an identifier, not an expression. (A qualified-id is a nested-name-specifier followed by an identifier, or some other things not relevant here).

I also don't understand why two different placeholders `x` and `ex`  are used in this sentence.  Saying "A appears as B" says to me that A and B are lexically identical but seeing A in the context of B has some extra meaning. At first I thought this might mean `x` is a more abstract way of talking about a variable (e.g. meaning the variable that is identified by `S::a`) and `ex` is an expression denoting that variable. However the quote goes on to say "Applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x`", therefore `x` is actually an expression after all; so I don't see what the difference is between `x` and `ex`.

Further, I am not sure what "an expression `e`" refers to exactly. I guess it is an existential taken over all expressions in the program such that `ex` is a subexpression of `e`.

Comment: The wording of [basic.def.odr]/3 is indeed a bit sloppy. See https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/414#issuecomment-69840696 .

Comment: @cpplearner OK. Do you think that "name" is supposed to refer to `S::a` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sloppy drafting seems to have been fixed in the C++23 draft by [P1787R6](https://wg21.link/P1787R6).

[basic.def.odr]/5:

> A variable is named by an expression if the expression is an *id-expression* that denotes it. A variable `x` that is named by a potentially-evaluated expression *E* is odr-used by *E* unless [...]

`S::a` is an *id-expression* and it names the variable in question.